# Insert space in php email form

Tags: php, email

i have a form that sends email through a PHP sender. The line related to the body of the email to be sent is:

```
$body = "New contact: " . $_POST['name'] . $_POST['email'] . $_POST['phone'];
```

So what happens is that name, email and phone fields come all together in the email, like: *New contact: Markmark@gmail.com1234567*

I wanted to insert an space between the fieds in php so i can easily read the different inputs. I know it's probably extremely easy to do that, but i've been searching for some time now and can't find the answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Concatenate the space between `. ' ' .` functional example: `$_POST['email'] . ' ' . $_POST['phone']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do concatenation of strings.

```
$body = "New contact: ". $_POST['name'] ." ". $_POST['email'] ." ". $_POST['phone'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$body = "New contact: " . $_POST['name'] ." ". $_POST['email'] . " ". $_POST['phone'];
```

or

```
$body = "New contact: " . $_POST['name'] ."&nbsp;". $_POST['email'] . "&nbsp;". $_POST['phone'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one concatinate

```
 $body = "New contact: '". $_POST['name']."'." ".'". $_POST['email']."'." ". '".$_POST['phone']."'";
```